# Activity on the More... tab sets UIViewController toolbarHidden to YES

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, toolbar

I have a `UIViewController` on the More... tab.  In `viewDidLoad`, I set `toolbarHidden` to NO, and the toolbar appears.  However, if I select another tab from More..., then when I return to my original `UIViewController`, the toolbar is hidden (`toolbarHidden` is YES).  I've checked to be sure it's the same view controller object.

My workaround is to set `toolBarHidden` to NO in `viewWillAppear`.

Is this documented behavior that I'm missing or is it a bug?

UPDATE

Here is some  fairly trivial sample code.  It turns on the toolbar in `viewDidLoad` and offers a button to toggle the toolbar on and off.

```
//  Test_VC.m
#import "Test_VC.h"

@implementation Test_VC

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // for testing to turn the toolbar on and off
    UIBarButtonItem *sampleButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                    initWithTitle:@"Toggle TB"
                                    style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                    target:self action:@selector(toggleToolbar:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = sampleButton;

    // the toolbar should re-appear whenver this view controller is selected
    self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    // if on More..., this line will keep toolbar visible
    //[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:NO];
}

- (void)toggleToolbar:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:!self.navigationController.toolbarHidden animated:YES];
}

@end
```

To test:

1. Create a project with numerous tabs, each of which is an instance of this view controller, Test_VC.  Have enough tabs so that at least two of these controllers are on the More tab.
2. Run the app.
3. Go to the More tab.
4. Select a "Test_VC" on More (I refer to this as "Test_1").  Notice that the toolbar appears.
5. Select another Test_VC from More. (I refer to this as "Test_2").  Notice that the toolbar also appears.
6. Touch "Toggle TB".  Notice that the toolbar goes away on Test_2.
7. Touch More.
8. Reselect the first Test VC ("Test_1").  Notice that the toolbar is no longer there.
9. Repeat these tests using Main tab view controllers.  Notice that there is no interactions with any others.

In step 4, the toolbar for Test_1 was present.  In step 6, the Test_2 toolbar is removed.  However, in step 8, the Test_1 toolbar is gone, too, but no change was made to the Test_1 VC.

This demo turns the toolbar on and off via the Toggle TB button.  In my app,  some of my view controllers simply hide the toolbar in `viewDidLoad` and some don't.  This demo code could be modified to make two view controller versions: some that show the toolbar in `viewDidLoad` and some that hide the toolbar in `viewDidLoad` (no need for the Toggle button).

If these view controllers are main tabs (step 9), then each operates independently of the others, as expected.

What I have found: Toolbar visibility on all view controllers launched from More is set by the most recent More view controller that executes `viewDidLoad`.  Thus, `viewDidLoad` is strange for More tab view controllers.

It's as if there's only one toolbar managed by More.  I do not understand this behavior.

Comment: No it's not a bug because `viewDidLoad` is entered once the `UIViewController` is created, if you navigate to another `ViewController` and get back to the original one, the original view controller is already loaded so `viewDidLoad` will not trigger so setting `toolBarHidden` to NO in `viewWillAppear` is a solution not a workaround

Comment: I know `viewDidLoad` on my first view controller will only execute once.  However, I don't expect `viewDidLoad` for a second view controller to have any effect on the state of my first view controller.  If that was true, then anything done in any `viewDidLoad` would affect all view controllers on the More... tab.  The state of my first view controller should not be changed by loading another view controller.  Why is this not true on the More... tab?

Comment: can you please post some code so I can help you more